# Pine Script - dynamic variables not working with ta.lowest/ta.highest

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When I use a dynamic value in the variable for the length argument in the ta.lowest(source, length) function it does not work.  If I hard code the value it does.  In 2020, TradingView announced that dynamically calculated lengths could be used in the lowest function, [article](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-functions-support-dynamic-length-arguments-20554/)  .  However, I can't get it to work.  The code compiles without errors, but on the chart I get the red circle exclamation point with the message:

> `Study Error: Error on bar 0: Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0) in the lowest function. It must be > 0.`

```
// @version = 5
indicator(title="Fibonacci Retracement", shorttitle="Fib Retrace", overlay = true)

i_LookBackPeriods = input.int(defval=60, title="Periods To Look Back", group="Options")
i_HighestBar      = ta.highestbars(i_LookBackPeriods + 1) * -1
i_LocalLookBack   = i_HighestBar - 1
f_LocalClose      = ta.lowest(close, i_LocalLookBack)
```

The above code does not work, but if I change i_LocalLookBack to the following it does.

```
i_LocalLookBack   = 52
```

Can you see what I am doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake here is two-fold:

1. The first bar given by the `ta.highestbars()` function will be a na value. This is causing the `Error on bar 0` error.
2. The calculated length of the `i_LocalLookBack` variable becomes less than zero. This is causing the `It must be > 0` error.

The code can be fixed by the following changes:

```
// @version = 5
indicator(title="Fibonacci Retracement", shorttitle="Fib Retrace", overlay = true)

i_LookBackPeriods = input.int(defval=60, title="Periods To Look Back", group="Options")
i_HighestBar      = nz(ta.highestbars(i_LookBackPeriods + 1) * -1)

i_LocalLookBack   = i_HighestBar - 1 <= 0 ? 1 : i_HighestBar - 1
f_LocalClose      = ta.lowest(close, i_LocalLookBack)
```

Explanation:

1. The `nz()` function around the `ta.highestbars()` function will prevent the `Error on bar 0` error.
2. Making it so that `i_HighestBar - 1` becomes 1 whenever it is less than zero, prevents the `It must be > 0` error.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Your suggestion of `i_HighestBar - 1 <= 0 ? 1 : i_HighestBar - 1` solves a problem I would have ran into in the next step.  However, the original problem still remains.  When the value for `i_LocalLookBack` is calculated it generates the error.

Comment: What type of error is it giving for you?

Comment: Rakesh - thank you so much.  I don't know why it couldn't get it to work yesterday but after a good nights sleep I pulled it up again and your solution fixed my original problem.